# broadcom STA wireless driver crash

Tags: wireless

I recently installed ubuntu 12.04lts on my dell inspiron 2200 everything is working fine except for the wireless driver I've installed Broadcom STA wireless driver over 5 times and each time at the end of the install it goes to a black screen with a bunch of info where I still am able to move the mouse but nothing else I have to reboot my computer to do anything else and in the network bar the wireless enabled has disappeared along with anything else having to do with the wireless network!

Comment: Please open the terminal(ctrl+alt+t) run the commands one line at a time: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
`lsusb`
`nm-tool`
`sudo iwlist scan`
`iwconfig`
`rfkill list all`
`lsmod` post the output at http://pastebin.com/ then post the link here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think these pages may help you. I had a problem with a broadcom and this is where I found the information that helped me.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BroadcomSTA%28Wireless%29

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx